# What the best "Add To Cart" button action?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, shopping-cart, cta

**In which situation should I choose each of the alternative bellows?**

After click on "Add To Cart" Button:

**1. Keep on the current page**, make animation on the "Add to cart" button to show the item was added and show a bubble message on the mini-cart at on the header.

[image]

**2.  Keep on the current page**, scroll the screen to frequently bought together and show a message that the product was added on the cart.

[image]

**3. Open a modal** with continue buying and go to checkout buttons and frequently bought together items.

[image]

**4. Go to an intermediary page** like Amazon are doing.

[image]

**5. Redirect to the shopping cart** and guarantee that has a continue buying button there.

*Ps: I already read [Do we need to show Cart page after the user clicked “Add to Cart” from list page?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38600/do-we-need-to-show-cart-page-after-user-clicked-add-to-cart-from-list-page) and [What is the best eCommerce add-to-cart flow](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134/what-is-the-best-ecommerce-add-to-cart-flow)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying on the same page is always a better actions to not confuse customers. Adding basket is fully other action than navigating to the basket.

On the other hand, *it also depends on what you want clients to do*...

**If user typically buy one kind of item**

It will make for your clients easier to navigate them to basket as Amazon did. Or showing it as a pop-up. And I would do that just once... If users want to shop further once, I would never redirect them again to the basket again.

**If you want your users to discover more items...**

Then I would suggest to stay on the same page, by showing an overview that the item is correctly added to the basket. Users then would feel that they should take some kind of action to accomplish it. Showing another options right on this moment (like relevant products or discounted things) would stimulate users more since they are thinking that some actions are needed.

Comment: Good viewpoint. In my case, the user normally buys more than one item and is important to show frequently bought together because it usually needs to complete their project with fixings and other roofing materials. Which option do you suggest to me?

Comment: Then I would definitely go for your 2. option. 1) user is navigationally aware where he is. 2) it is shown visually that the product is added and ready to go. 3) he feels that he has to take some actions in order to go further and in the meanwhile see other complementary or relevant products in the main focus of the screen. 4) he would not hesitate to take further actions since he is not lost navigationally. 5) Alongside with view product, add to basket button/text would also be helpful in the relevant products shown to user